# Error resolving placeholders in springboot application with config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configserver

I am configuring config server to use in a springboot application
The application has recently been migrated from spring to springboot so most of the properties are used in applicationContext.xml files

Example :

```
<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">      
    <property name="address" value="${rabbitmq.address}"/>
</bean>
```

> This throw an IllegalArgumentException : Could not resolve placeholder

I also have my configuration Properties file to load some properties by prefix, and I can use my properties if I declare them in the class below:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ConfiguationProperties {}
```

But I don't want to put all the properties in the configuration properties file and keep my applicationContext directly loading properties using placeholders syntax, is there a possibility?

Comment: have you created configuration class, where you imported your xml configs? like: `@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class XmlConfiguration {
}`

Comment: specify the properties file location in xml file `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>`

Comment: @BSeitkazin yes i imported my applicationContext.xml in the main springboot class

Comment: @Deadpool it is not working because property files loaded by the cloud config server are not available on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

My error was that the path to my configuration files was incorrect because my properties files were in a subdirectory of my config path ${config-path}/subdirectory/myapplication-dev.properties

i removed the subdirectory and it works fine. It seems that the config server load correctly the properties files in the classpath only if it respects the schema url :

```
 http://localhost:8888/${my-profile}/myapplication
```

and not :

```
http://localhost:8888/subdirectory/${my-profile}/myapplication
```

(event if i can see my properties in the web browser with this url)